# I can't display alert when I pressed my recalculate button

Tags: ios, swift, button, uikit, alert

I designed an app in iOS. I have 2 viewcontroller and in secondview there is a button to press recalculate. I want to show alert message to ask "Are you sure to recalculate" or something like that. Even if I did if condition, ios didnt show me alert message
[secondview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awGtO.png)

This is my storyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyifF.png)

I try to show my alert message but when I pressed my button pass primary page

Comment: Please see [ask], including the section on including code as text, not images, and making a [mre]

Comment: I think you don't have navigation controller
In the first View Controller Do you have a Navigation Controller, If you want to navigate to other View Controller you should have a navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RootViewController should start with a UINavigationController, And each segue way should have its own Identifier.

In this link you can check it step by step:
https://vasundhara.io/blogs/navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-using-swift

I think your issue is for not having a UINavigationController.

Comment: thank you so much actually I directly bound button to primary view controller but this is unnecesary because I try to create another button and copy paste this code and its work so I delete direct bound button from primary view and add a bound secondviewcontroller to primarycontroller then it worked